# Set Customer Email in Magento

Tags: magento, frameworks, magento-1.7, e-commerce

I have an issue with my Magento Checkout, when I checkout as a guest it doesn't seem to recognise the email address that a user has entered within the billing details checkout process.

Can anyone explain how to write something like the following, below is my psuedocode:

```
if (Customer Email is EMPTY)
    set Customer Email to email stored in the order object
```

I know that when I output the following it gives me the email address (within an observer):

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
echo $order->getBillingAddress()->getEmail();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed - needed a if statement, no customer object on the guest therefore was always failing... arrghh silly Mage

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify in which part you were attempting to get the guest email, I'm going to assume you want it on success:

```
 $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($this->getOrderId());
 echo $order->getCustomerEmail();
```

**EDIT:** For after billing section, below should work. I tested it in the Payment section.

`Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getBillingAddress()->getEmail()`

Comment: It will be after the billing details section so i presume i would need sales/quote?

Answer (score 1):

first of all apply client side validation on email field. apply these classes "`validate-email required-entry`" in email field on checkout page like

`<input type="text" class="input-text validate-email required-entry" title="Email Address" value="" id="billing:email" name="billing[email]">`

after that use below code to validate the email field on server side:
I assume you are using third party extension for checkout. so you need to debug what controller & action called for save billing address. for example you can use firebug in mozila browser if third party extension is using json or ajax or you need to debug manually.

In your module config file call a observer function on event after fill the billing address.

```
<events>
    <controller_action_predispatch_[module]_[controller]_[action]>
        <observers>
            <Observer_Name>
                <class>[Package]_[Module]_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>checkEmail</method>
            </Observer_Name>
        </observers>
    </controller_action_predispatch_[module]_[controller]_[action]>
</events>
```

crate a observer model class:

```
 class [Package]_[Module]_Model_Observer
    {

       public function checkEmail(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) 
        {
                // example code         
                $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('billing', array()); // you need to check what filed are posted for billing address or email address 

            if (!isset($data['email'])) {
                return $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
            }

        }

    }
```

Hope this helps you!